# max data in one column based on another column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

Hello I am very new to SQL programming, started last week.  I am trying to select a userID and Maxdate from a table that looks like this for example:

```
Key    USERID     Date
1      111        12/1/2014
2      202        4/1/2014
3      111        3/8/2014
4      111        2/5/2014
5      202        2/10/2014
```

I want to make a query that would end up with the following results:

```
USERID     DATE
111        12/1/2014
202        4/1/2014
```

Comment: This is a basic aggregation query using `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **GROUP BY** clause with aggregate function **MAX** to achieve this:

Try this:

```
SELECT USERID, MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY USERID
```